# difference between TOMCAT server and BEA WEBLOGIC server

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, weblogic

What is difference between TOMCAT server and BEA WEBLOGIC server

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tomcat is a Servlet/JSP container. It is free. It does not support the Java EE 6 container features such as EJB/JPA out of the box. 
These can be integrated but will not be equivalent to a proper EJB container.

WebLogic Server is a fully loaded EJB container. It has the best server and database connection pooling features in the market. It is easy to build/deploy/debug apps on Weblogic.
It's a commercial product and quite expensive at that.

Comment: EJB is history right.

Comment: @VishnudevK: EJB 3 isnt

Answer (score 12):

Apache Tomcat is an open sources Servlet/JSP container (it was the Reference Implementation for the Servlet/JSP APIs prior to Servlet 2.5/JSP 2.1), it does not implement the whole Java EE stack (no EJB container, no JTA, no JMS, etc). Tomcat "competes" with [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/) and [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/) but is not comparable with a Java EE certified server.

<strike>BEA</strike>Oracle WebLogic Server is a commercial Java EE application server that implements the whole Java EE specification. It is known to be a mature, extremely stable, secure, performant application server and is used in many "mission critical" applications. In short, it's the Rolls-Royce of application servers. But it's expensive too. WebLogic competitors are WebSphere (commercial), JBoss, GlassFish, Geronimo, Jonas (open source).